# Umbraco 7 Archetype unable to get media udi

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have read these posts

https://our.umbraco.org/forum/templates-partial-views-and-macros/85993-archetype-mediapicker-udi

https://our.umbraco.org/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/85598-getting-image-url-from-media-picker-not-working-in-76

http://www.codeshare.co.uk/blog/how-to-get-the-file-path-of-a-media-item-in-umbraco/

but I'm still unable to get the value from the media picker.

On my last attempt, I got the following error.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

If I try the following:

```
string img = "";
            foreach (var d in archtypePanel.Properties)
            {
                if (d.Alias == "imageToDisplay")
                {
                    img = d.Value.ToString();
                }
            }
```

I can see the media UDI: "umb://media/15cc14d318f3444a86ab3bc7fc5787ad" but I'm unable to get any further.

I have now run into a wall, so any help on solving this issue will be helpful.

My last attempt is below:

```
Guid idValue = new Guid(id);
            var blogPosts = CurrentPage;
            IPublishedContent blogPosts2 = CurrentPage;
            var archtypePanel = blogPosts2.GetPropertyValue<ArchetypeModel>("blogArchetypes").First(x=>x.Id == idValue);

            ArchetypeWithTextAndImageModel model = new ArchetypeWithTextAndImageModel
            {
                TextContent = new HtmlString(archtypePanel.GetValue("textRichTextEditor")),
                ImageId     = archtypePanel.GetValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("imageToDisplay").ToString()// imgUrl
            };
```

But ImageId throws the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Access from strong type model

make sure your [Umbraco-Core-Property-Value-Converters](https://github.com/Jeavon/Umbraco-Core-Property-Value-Converters) is updated to latest

and also in `umbracoSettings.config`  `<EnablePropertyValueConverters>true</EnablePropertyValueConverters>` is set to true

then access your media url via
`archtypePanel.GetPropertyValue<IPublishedContent>("imageToDisplay").Url`

### Access using udi url

another way is by using the udi url you have got and get media like:

```
// Your string which is retrieved from Archetype.
var imageString = "umb://media/c33bfe07a82b4df18a79db154139cb91";

// Get the guid from this string.
var imageGuidUdi = GuidUdi.Parse(imageString);

// Get the ID of the node!
var imageNodeId = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.EntityService.GetIdForKey(guidUdi.Guid, (UmbracoObjectTypes)Enum.Parse(typeof(UmbracoObjectTypes), guidUdi.EntityType, true));

// Finally, get the node.
var imageNode = Umbraco.TypedMedia(imageNodeId.Result);
```

more info about this, checkout [Umbaco Archtype rendering images (MediaPicker2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44306120/umbaco-archtype-rendering-images-mediapicker2)

Comment: Hi @Alan Tsai thanks for the reply, seems in my case the install of a new Umbraco was corrupt, I saved the project to TFS and then removed all Nuget packages and then re-installed them. I then compared config files and old version had lots of attributes and elements missing. It now works with: ImageId     = archtypePanel.GetValue<IPublishedContent>("imageToDisplay").Url which did not work previously

Comment: Umbraco.TypedMedia supports a Udi as a parameter, no need for that extra call to GetIdForKey.  This is simpler and will accomplish the same thing:
`var imageNode = Umbraco.TypedMedia(imageGuidUdi);`

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try this:

```
@using Umbraco.Web.Extensions
string HeaderImage = "umb://media/c740e797fc424980afb087769caf0917";
Udi udi;
if (Udi.TryParse(HeaderImage.ToString(), out udi))
{
  var mediaItem = udi.ToPublishedContent();
  string ImageURL = mediaItem.Url;
      <div class="col-sm-3">
           <img src="@ImageURL">
      </div>
}
```

([Source](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/extending-umbraco-and-using-the-api/85119-using-the-new-umbdocumentguid))

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me:

```
var countryUrl = "umb://document/72e07554a09d4d8ab6af7ad926c9a3c4";                   
var countryGuidUdi = GuidUdi.Parse(countryUrl);  

var countryNodeId = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.EntityService.GetIdForKey(countryGuidUdi.Guid, (UmbracoObjectTypes)Enum.Parse(typeof(UmbracoObjectTypes), countryGuidUdi.EntityType, true));

var countryName = Umbraco.TypedContent(countryNodeId.Result).Name;

var countryCode = Umbraco.TypedContent(countryNodeId.Result).GetProperty("countryCode").Value;
```